# How to have default invitees for any meeting in Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I usually need to involve some of my colleagues but they aren't directly involved in what I do, so I usually forget to invite them!

Is there a way to have default invitees for any meeting in Google calendar? This way I can remove them if their presence isn't necessary. Also inviting them by mistake isn't as harmful as completely forgetting them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to study
[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar),
in order to create or modify calendar events.

You might also need to study the
[Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar),
described as:

> The advanced Calendar service allows you to use the public
> [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar)
> in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's
> [built-in Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar),
> this API allows scripts to access and modify the user's Google Calendar, including additional calendars that the user is subscribed to. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this advanced service provides a few extra features, including setting the background color for individual events.

Comment: Thanks but how can this automate adding attendees for me? I know that I can write app script code in a Google sheet. But how can I do this for my Calendar?